# How to align text and icon in bootstrap nav bar

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am working an Angular 4 application ,In this I have a navigation bar with text and font awesome icons .

It's UI is fine in web view but when it comes to mobile view (minimized screen) it is not aligned how I expect .

I have tried my best but I can't fix it .

In Minimized view :

[image]

How I expect :(example)

[image]

Here I have attached the stackblitz file : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bootstrap-carousel-dynamic2-w1qhj4?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

Answer (score -1):

`xs` applies to every screen size if nothing else is provided, `sm` doesn't apply to mobile screens.

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-xs-12"> <!-- Changes -->
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">

            <div class="col-xs-2">  <!-- Changes -->
              <i class="fas fa-phone text-white" style="font-size:40px"></i>
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-10">  <!-- Changes -->
              <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                  <span class="text-white text-uppercase col-sm-12">Demo 1</span>
                  <span class="text-white col-sm12" style="margin-left: 14px">Text Text</span>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Apply these changes

Comment: `xs` applies to every screen size if nothing else is provided, `sm` doesn't applies to mobile screens.

Comment: But I can't get it aligned in center ,Can you give me any suggestion to do that @SumanKundu

Comment: Try adding `mx-auto` class beside `row`, what it does is set `margin` left & right to `auto`.